# In Diablo III, how can I change what Chat region I'm in, or join a global channel?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I log into Diablo, it appears that I'm placed into a mini-region of sorts for chatting - the general chat seems to be limited to 99 people, and the specialized chat rooms have very small amounts of people in them, I assume because I'm in a mini-region of sorts. This region seems to change every time I log out/log in.

Is there a way to change this region without logging out/in, or is there a global channel I can join?  Say I want to join Witch Doctor chat, and there are only 7 people in it, that is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to change this region selectively.

(Fortunately)There's no public chat that allows all people in, either. The reason for this is obvious: Imagine a chat room with thousands of people in it. I think it would be impossible to have any conversation with anybody when that chat is active.

Comment: Hopefully sometime in the future they allow you to change chats; at the moment, it's pretty useless.